# Java Receiving CORBA Callback with Swing

Tags: java, callback, corba

I have a class that extends Swing JFrame. In order for this class to receive a callback and call a method in this class, the class should extend the POA class.   I don't know how to do that.  What about multiple inheritance? Should I make another class that extends the POA class?

Code

```
public final class JFSECorbaClient extends javax.swing.JFrame {

//
// init and other method
//

public static void main(final String args[]) throws ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException{

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                frame = new JFSECorbaClient().setVisible(true);
                try {

                    //initialize orb
                    Properties props = System.getProperties();
                    props.put("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "1050");
                    props.put("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "localhost");
                    ORB orb = ORB.init(args, props);
                    System.out.println("Initialized ORB");

                    //Instantiate Servant and create reference
                    POA rootPOA = POAHelper.narrow(
                            orb.resolve_initial_references("RootPOA"));
                    rootPOA.activate_object(this.frame); //this.frame should extends jfseCallbackPOA
                    ref = jfseCallbackHelper.narrow(
                            rootPOA.servant_to_reference(callbackListener));

                    //Resolve MessageServer
                    jfseServer = jfseORBHelper.narrow(
                            orb.string_to_object("corbaname:iiop:1.2@localhost:1050#MessageServer"));

                    //Activate rootpoa
                    rootPOA.the_POAManager().activate();
                    //thread for receive callback in other class thread
                    JFSECorrbaListener th = new JFSECorrbaListener();
                    th.setOrb(orb);
                    th.start();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't have to extend the POA class if you are in control of the IDL: you can define your callback via RMI/IIOP, generate the IDL from the remote interface when generating the stub (rmic -iiop), and use PortableRemoteObject.exportObject() to export it. No need to extend any specific class.

Having said all that, it's the wrong answer. Your JFrame-extending class has no need to also be a CORBA callback. Define your CORBA callback as a completely separate class, and provide it with hooks into your JFrame-extending class to do whatever is required when the callback occurs.